# Flutter TextEditingController - Disposal & Initiation Requirements?

Tags: flutter, texteditingcontroller

I am creating 100's of TextEditing Controllers in my app.
Here's what im doing:

```
TextEditingController _customerName = TextEditingController();
```

I'm just curious, but if I have 100s of these elements, am I meant to do anything in

```
@override
void initState()
{ .... }
```

or

```
@override
void dispose()
{... }
```

???

Im just asking as my app is sluggish and I have a feeling it maybe because I'm using 1000s of these controllers.

Thanks

Comment: guys, come on..it was a fair question. there's no need to downgrade me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should dispose every TextEditingController before disposing its screen.
For example:

```
@override
void dispose() {
    _customerName.dispose();
    super.dispose();
}
```

Docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html